# Maven doesn't copy jars to classpath (with STS)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring tool suite 4 with Maven for development. 
I use jdbc in my project and I added the connector jar as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I also checked if the IDE's build path contains my maven deps (as per other solutions suggested):

[image]

but I still get the class not found problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used an old (1.x) version of Hibernate out of mistake. I also updated my `jdbc-connection` to the latest today (right now 8.0.16). The problem is gone now.